# Why can't I filter a subscription?

Tags: elm

Why does [Platform.Sub](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.1/Platform-Sub) not expose any filter functions? It would be really handy to have a function like `filterMap : (a -> Maybe msg) -> Sub a -> Sub msg` to listen, for example, for events on some keys but not others.

Can this functionality be implemented another way, and is it a good idea?

Answer (score 4):

While I can't speak to its absence (`filterMap` certainly seems reasonable), you can have a workaround by doing a filter/map before your `update` function and map to a `NoOp` message when your filter returns `Nothing`:

```elm
import Maybe

yourFilterFunction : Msg -> Maybe Msg
yourFilterFunction = ...

main =
  Html.program
    { init = init
    , view = view
    , update = update << Maybe.withDefault NoOp << yourFilterFunction
    , subscriptions = subscriptions
    }
```

Your `NoOp` case in the `update` function would just return `model ! []`.

Comment: Still that pollutes a lot the update stack with many NoOp entries listed. Filtering before updating would be much better.